# JS Вызов на одно событие нескольких функций

Tags: javascript

При наведение на таблицу у меня вызывается 3 функции, как сделать так , что бы при наведении на таблицу выполнялись все 3 функции, но записывалось это в один ряд

```
this.Mytable.addEventListener('mousemove', this.funtion1.bind(this));
this.Mytable.addEventListener('mousemove', this.funtion2.bind(this));
this.Mytable.addEventListener('mousemove', this.funtion3.bind(this));
```

То бишь запись в коде `this.Mytable.addEventListener('mousemove'`, не дублировалась , а записывалась лишь раз

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.Mytable.addEventListener('mousemove', 
  (e) => { this.funtion1(e); this.funtion2(e); this.funtion3(e); });
```